# Cross Join in ArcGIS Pro/ Joining one value to many without join field

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-joins

I have an attribute table with one single value and an attribute table with different rows. I want to join the single entry to all rows from the other table, without using a certain join field  on which the join will be based. In SQL it would be a cross Join.

```
table 1     table 2 cross joined
x             a | d | c | x
              o | e | t | x
              f | b | c | x
```

Is that possible in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Just add a new field to table 2 and then do a field calculate on your new field to populate it with "X".

Comment: It should work with the model builder automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end the quick and dirty solution  "Join Field" -> "Fill Missing Values" (with this tool, missing values can be filled from the one field with a value) worked for me.